# AngularJS - Dynamic pattern to validate input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

Basically what I need to be able to register two types of code. The code type A has only numbers and the code Type B has numbers, one hyphen, one alphabetic value and one numeric value.

Hypothetical situation:

- I register the code type A, the custom directive validate all values.
- I need to register the code type B, I check the option 'Validate code
  Type B', the pattern is changed in order to make the validation, then all values entered are validated.

**Code - Type A**
12345678 
32445678 
56535678 

**Code with complement number - Type B**
32445678-a1
32445678-a2
65434567-b1

The form

```
<form>
  <span>Insert code:</span><br/>
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="code" code-type>  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="validateCodeTypeB" /> Validate code Type B
</form>
```

**Note:** When the 'validateCodeTypeB' option is checked the regex will be changed too. But I don't know how to implement the second regex in order to validate the code Type B.

See the [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/JWCNPFjjbgwkw2u35yhp?p=preview)

And the directive

```
app.directive('codeType', function () {
    return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
        function codeTypeA(text) {
          if (text) {
            var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

            if (transformedInput !== text) {
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                ngModelCtrl.$render();
            }
            return transformedInput;
          }
        return undefined;
        }            
        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(codeTypeA);
    }
    }  
});
```

Comment: you are having problem with regex too as well? or just issuing how to give it 2nd regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have made you plnkr for your solution:

```
if(!scope.codeType){
    transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); // For CodeTypeA
} else {
    transformedInput = text.replace(/[^a-z]/g,''); // For CodeTypeB, change it to your own regex
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/IfIeXhy7vZacLi2jKsMs?p=preview

but regex is different for CodetypeB , change it to your regex for codetypeB and its good to go.